# docker-compose mysql import failed - the input device is not a TTY

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have any running containers. So i need import sql databases and try

```
docker-compose exec MYSQL_CONTAINERNAME mysql -uroot -p --database=MY_DB < /code/export_new.sql
```

But I have message "docker-compose exec -i MYSQL_CONTAINER NAME mysql -uroot -p --database=MY_DB < /code/export_new.sql" If I use "-i" or "-T" or "-it" parameters after command "... exec " I have message:

```
Usage: exec [options] [-e KEY=VAL...] SERVICE COMMAND [ARGS...]

Options:
    -d, --detach      Detached mode: Run command in the background.
    --privileged      Give extended privileges to the process.
    -u, --user USER   Run the command as this user.
    -T                Disable pseudo-tty allocation. By default `docker-compose exec`
                      allocates a TTY.
    --index=index     index of the container if there are multiple
                      instances of a service [default: 1]
    -e, --env KEY=VAL Set environment variables (can be used multiple times,
                      not supported in API < 1.25)
    -w, --workdir DIR Path to workdir directory for this command.
```

How I can to import my "export_new.sql" into mysql, which placed in container?

Answer (score 13):

Worked for me with

```
docker-compose exec -T MYSQL_CONTAINERNAME mysql databasename < data.sql
```

Comment: Best solution imo, the -T option works like a charm.

Comment: This throws me `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: You may need to use a password for your user like in the original question "-p" it really depends on what is your DB configuration. The -T option is a fix only for "the input device is not a TTY" not anything else, hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Using `docker-compose exec` like this did not work (don't know why), but you can use `docker exec`. You just need to know the container name or id. Name is listed during `docker-compose up` or you can find out using `docker-compose ps`.

Here is an example command:

```
docker exec -i MYSQL_CONTAINERNAME mysql databasename < data.sql
```

Or you can combine `docker-compose ps` into it so that you only need to know the short name (defined in docker-compose.yml):

```
docker exec -i $(docker-compose ps -q MYSQL) mysql databasename < data.sql
```

Also, note that I had trouble using the above commands with -p flag so that it would ask for password interactively, but it worked when I passed the password in the initial command (e.g. `mysql -uroot -pmypwd`).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first you have to connect to your running mysql instance. You can do it with this command:

```
docker run -it --link some-mysql:mysql --rm mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"'
```

in this command change the string `some-mysql` with the name of your actual container. Variables correspond to:

- MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR - host (default: localhost)
- MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT - port (default: 3306)
- MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD - password of the root user

Then you will be able to execute commands directly on you mysql instance, co it will be enough to type:

```
MY_DB < /code/export_new.sql
```

For any troubleshooting or good source of information please read about mysql docker image here:
https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Answer (score 0):

If your docker DBMS has password you should use:

```
docker exec -i MYSQL_CONTAINERNAME mysql databasename_optional -ppassword < data.sql
```

The `databasename_optional` is optional since some DB Dumps sets the DB name on top of it like:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `databasename` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `databasename`;
```